# How to create "Two Content" Layout for slides using Python-pptx library

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have been trying to create the "two-content" slides layout where there is a title and some content to the left and right of vertically split section

My code is as follows:

```
import collections
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation

presentation = Presentation()
slide_layout = presentation.slide_layouts[5]
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
content1 = slide.placeholders[1]
content1.text = 'First content'
content2 = slide.placeholders[2]
content2.text = 'Second content'
presentation.save('presentation.pptx')
print("Presentation created successfully.")
```

I keep getting the following error
*PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Slide Generator\SlidesGenerator> & C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe "c:/Users/dell/Desktop/Slide Generator/SlidesGenerator/twocontent.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\dell\Desktop\Slide Generator\SlidesGenerator\twocontent.py", line 8, in 
content1 = slide.placeholders[1]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pptx\shapes\shapetree.py", line 766, in **getitem**
raise KeyError("no placeholder on this slide with idx == %d" % idx)
KeyError: 'no placeholder on this slide with idx == 1'*

Comment: Do those placeholders actually exist on the slide? Further, you can create text shapes with python-pptx - even without placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need slide layout 3

```
import collections
import collections.abc
from pptx import Presentation

presentation = Presentation()
slide_layout = presentation.slide_layouts[3]
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
content1 = slide.placeholders[1]
content1.text = 'First content'
content2 = slide.placeholders[2]
content2.text = 'Second content'
presentation.save('presentation.pptx')
print("Presentation created successfully.")
```